# Using city names to put marker on the map instead of using Latng and Long in javascript mapping library?

Tags: javascript, mapping, raphael, jvectormap

I am working on mapping project, and I would like to use city name to place my markers on the map. There are some javascript library that produces really good maps such as raphaeljs, and jvectormap. However, I have seen the use of these libraries with latng and long values. Can I instead use the city name to identify the location on the map, and place my marker?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a city name to a lat/long with geocoding: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: but the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map ?

Comment: There are other Geocoding APIs - Bing, for example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868061.aspx

Comment: Can you get the x and y coordinates of the markers you want to put as cities on the map?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar what I did in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jUTFm/48/). **But only** if you can place your city positions and text manually of course.

Also the code:

```
var paper = Raphael("notepad");

var c = paper.circle(30, 100, 3).attr({fill: 'red'});
var t = paper.text(50, 90, "Los Angeles").attr({fill: 'blue'}).hide();

c.hover(function () {
    t.show();
  },
  function () {
    t.hide();
  }
);
```